# 'yarn offline' use absolute path when setting 'yarn-offline-mirror' path

Tags: yarnpkg

I am trying to create yarn offline mirror. I followed the steps mentioned
[here](https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2016/11/24/offline-mirror/)

When setting `offline-mirror-dir` as in the link above:

> "$ yarn config set yarn-offline-mirror ./npm-packages-offline-cache"

where `./npm-packages-offline-cache` is an example location relative to home folder where all the source .tar.gz files will be downloaded to from the registry.

I need to set an absolute path instead of relative path? How can I do that?

```
$ yarn --version
1.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

For an absolute path simply specify the full path.  ( Which would start with root `/` instead of the dot `.` )  Example:

```
$ yarn config set yarn-offline-mirror /tmp/npm-packages-offline-cache
$ yarn install
$ ls /tmp/npm-packages-offline-cache
```

---

A path relative to where yarn is executed instead of home can be specified as follows:

```
$ yarn config set yarn-offline-mirror vendor/npm-packages-offline-cache
$ cd ~/my_project
$ yarn install
$ ls ~/my_project/vendor/npm-packages-offline-cache
```